# On the console pane of the Rstudio app, i get the message 'Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]:' Why is this?

Tags: rstudio

```
type here
         devtools::install_github("compgenomr/compGenomRData")
         Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
         system.file()
         Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
         R CMD INSTALL compGenomRData-1.0.tar.gz
         Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
         devtools::install_github("compgenomr/compGenomRData")
         Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
         R CMD INSTALL compGenomRData-1.0.tar.gz
         Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]:  
         2+2
         Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
         2-2
         Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]:
```

I have just finished installing some packages and whenever I try to do a simple task such as a calculation, I get the same message in the console.
Please help
This is an example:

I wasn't expecting this

Answer (score 0):

RStudio is asking you which sources you want to update.

By typing `a`, you will update all. `s` is for some, and `n` for none. Any other input is not understood.